# How to pass custom props in a Bootstrap Table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-table, react-props

I want to render a list of {key, value} pairs that I get from the API. In order to display it,  I need to pass them as custom props in a bootstrap table component.

So, I do the following:

```
{config && (
 <table>
  <tbody
   data={addData(ConfigData(config), configInfo)}
   listRow={configListRow}
  />
 </table>
)}
```

But if I do it like that, I get the following error:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `listRow` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `listrow` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

Now if I rename it to a `lowercase` as React Suggest, I get this:

```
Warning: Invalid value for prop `listrow` on <tbody> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see ...
```

Now if I rename it to a String, I don't get any errors, but I do not get my data, or the table at all. Can you help me a bit here? I mean what is the problem with this implementation.

Comment: Are you using React-Bootstrap?

Comment: I am in my project, not on this specific instnace..

Comment: That is not a react prop as you are using a standard DOM element of tbody. React is just passing listRow on to the actual DOM element which is malformed html. Where are you even trying to read the listRow prop? You should be doing things inside the tbody tag.

Comment: @GifCo, So, if I do this `<tbody data={data={addData(ConfigData(config), configInfo)} />` I should at least get some kind of Data. But I get nothing.

Comment: But the question remains, how do I correctly pass those props down to a plain old Bootstrap table..??

Comment: I have no idea what the data attribute is doing? You cant just fill a table with data like that unless you are using some other library? You also dont want to pass a prop to a plain old table element you have no way of accessing it. Props are for react components not HTML DOM elements.

Comment: Ok, let's say I want to display the Data, that this spits out `addData(ConfigData(config)`, how would I do that? If I do this `<tbody>{addSqlData(configData(config), configInfo)}</tbody>` , I would get an error, that this is an object.

Comment: I guess I could do JSON.Stringify, but that is not a good Idea. I guess the question here, is how to render an object in JSX...

Comment: whatever addSqlDate() is must return valid html or react components. If you dont have control of that function then get the results from it and map over them spitting out <tr> and <td>'s